# Eventos JQuery no funcionan en Modal Bootstrap con Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Trabajando con `radio buttons` dentro de un `modal` me surgieron problemas, ya que por medio de la selección de dichos `input radio` se llena un formulario de paypal.

Es decir, son 4 `radio buttons` y cada uno tiene un `value` distinto.

```
<input type="radio" id="id-5" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="5">
<input type="radio" id="id-20" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="20">
<input type="radio" id="id-50" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="50">
<input type="radio" id="id-100" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="100">
```

Pero, estos están dentro de un modal y básicamente lo que trato de hacer es que al seleccionar uno de los `radio buttons` me pase el valor del value a un campo de un formulario (paypal). Hay surge el inconveniente, se como asignar los valores pero en esta ocasión no funciona.

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="10">
```

Y lo intente de la siguiente manera:

```
$('input.paquetes').click(function(){
    $('#quantity').val($(this).val());
});
/******************************************/
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $('#quantity').val($(this).val());
});
/******************************************/
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
    $('#quantity').val($(this).val());
});
```

También directamente por el atributo `id`, `clase`, usando `click`, usando `change`, usando `on()`, etc. Aun así no logro que entre siquiera al evento y `JQuery` esta funcionando perfectamente porque el resto del sitio funciona con el y no tiene problema alguno.

El `modal` está así:

```
<div class="modal slideInUp fade text-left animated" id="tokens" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Dentro tiene los `radio buttons` y el `form` de `paypal`.

Comment: Asegúrate de que sea posible modificar el valor del input escondido. Yo he trabajado con Stripe y hacer eso es practicamente imposible (por seguridad), había que hacerlo a través de su API. Tal vez suceda algo parecido con PayPal

Comment: @César Pero eso lo creería si aunque sea entrara al evento, pero ni siquiera entra al evento click o change, ni mostrando un simple alert. Eso es lo curioso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `JQuery` los elementos dentro del `modal` los identificas asi:

```
// 'tokens' es el 'id' de tu modal
$("#tokens").find("input[type=radio]")
```

Entonces te sugiero probar lo siguiente:

```
$("#tokens").find("input[type=radio]").on('change', function() {
    alert($('input[name=paquetes]:checked').val());
});
```

Aqui te dejo un Code Snipet usando radios en un modal de bootstrap

```js
$(function(){
  $("#modal_tokens").find("input[type=radio]").on('change', function() {
    alert($('input[name=paquetes]:checked').val())
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_tokens">
  Mostrar Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_tokens" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="radio" id="id-5" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="5"> 5 <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="id-20" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="20"> 20 <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="id-50" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="50"> 50 <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="id-100" class="o_input" name="paquetes" value="100"> 100
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ni de esa manera me funciono amigo, ya lo intente anteriormente, al igual ahorita copie tu código y no funciona, me tiene bastante frustrado esto.

Comment: Acabo de notar que tu forma de obtener el valor de tu radio estaba mal. Hice la correccion y te deje un ejemplo practico.